# Validator to check if the password contains at least 1 letter or number

Tags: html, angular, angular2-forms

I need to check the user input password if it contains a letter to make it stronger. If the password only contains only numbers or letters, it should prompt that the password is weak and the form is invalid. Here is my code.

```
ngOnInit(){
        this.registrationForm = this._formBuilder.group({
            password: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(8)]]
        });
    }
```

html code

```
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password" class="cols-sm-2 control-label">Password</label>
                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-lock fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        <input type="password" [(ngModel)]="user.password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Enter your Password" formControlName="password"/>
                    </div>
                    <span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls.password.hasError('required') && registrationForm.get('password').touched" class="alert alert-danger">Password is required</span>
                    <span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls.password.hasError('minlength') && registrationForm.get('password').touched" class="alert alert-danger">Password should consist of 8 characters</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

EDIT: How can I check the user input if it contains a letter and number and returns weak password if it only contains number only or letter only?

Comment: What exactly is the issue here? All you've done is thrown some code at us with a small explanation, are you having an issue? Why is this a question? Please edit.

Comment: edited. added the question. thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem using Regex.

```
passwordRegex = /^([0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+|[a-zA-Z]+[0-9]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]*$/;
```

This will check if the password contains at least one letter or number. Then add validation in my html.

```
<span *ngIf="registrationForm.controls.password.hasError('pattern') && registrationForm.get('password').touched" class="alert alert-danger">Weak password</span>
```